# Convertir base de datos Access a extensión .jql

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Tengo una base de datos la cual quiero importar a MySQL, pero he visto que el único método para hacer esto es convirtiendo la base de datos de Access en un archivo.sql, el problema es que he descargado programas y he visto tutoriales de como convertirlo pero ninguno me ha funcionado, si alguien sabe como convertir una base de datos tipo Access a un archivo con extensión .jql ¿podrían darme algún consejo o recomendarme algún programa?

Comment: `mysqli` es una extensión de PHP para conectarse a mysql, me parece que la etiqueta que buscas usar es `mysql`

Comment: gracias, no me di cuenta que seleccione esa etiqueta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para importar de MySQL (u otra base de datos) desde Access lo que yo siempre hice (seguramente no lo mas eficiente) es exportar a Excel desde Access y generar consultas de inserción concatenando las columnas.

Por ejemplo:

```
="insert into tabla (id,camñpo1,campo2) values (" & a1 & ",'" & b1 & "','" & c1 & "');"
```

y luego ejecutar las query simplemente copiando y pegando en phpMyAdmin

Comment: Y ¿Cómo creas las relaciones entre tablas?

Comment: simplemente es para copiar los datos, no se genera la estructura ni las relaciones, eso lo hago a mano en phpmyadmin. Esto me sirve mas que nada cuando las estructuras de datos son diferentes. Por eso digo que seguramente no es lo mas eficiente, pero a mi me sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo a través de la exportación de las tablas mediante ODBC a MySQL, o a cualquier otra BBDD que tenga conector ODBC.
Pulsando con el botón derecho sobre la tabla Exportar-->Bases de datos ODBC.
Sigue los pasos que te van indicando y es relativamente sencillo. Previamente tienes que tener el Driver de MySQL instalado. En la página oficial de MySQL tienes el download para el driver para ODBC.