# Guardar datos de excel en SQL Server

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen que se ve, es un datagridview, los datos los saco de un archivo de excel, mi pregunta es como pasar esos datos a una tabla como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Normalmente para insertar los registros de un datagrid uso un foreach para leer los datos, pero en este caso, no se si se podra como poner un switch o algo por el estilo, porque dependiendo de los datos, los numeros de la columna num van cambiando, y quiero insertar los registros a partir del numero que esta en la columna num, por decir segun el dato que hay en el datagrid, estos se deberían guardar desde la columna T220 porque la numeración comienza a partir del 22 y terminar en el 27 = T270

y este es el codigo que uso:

```
private void btnImportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvExcel.RowCount != 0)
        {
            int programa = Convert.ToInt32(dgvExcel.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
            int lote = Convert.ToInt32(dgvExcel.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
            String modelo = Convert.ToString(dgvExcel.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);
            String color = Convert.ToString(dgvExcel.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value);
            String linea = Convert.ToString(dgvExcel.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
            String cliente = Convert.ToString(dgvExcel.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value);
            int pedido = Convert.ToInt32(dgvExcel.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
            DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvExcel.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value);

            //instruccion para mandar los datos a la clase que hace la insercion de datos
            biss.InfoLote(programa, modelo, color, linea, cliente, pedido, fecha.ToShortDateString());

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvExcel.Rows)
            {
                string fila = dgvExcel[0, row.Index].Value.ToString();
                if (fila != "")
                {
                    int T1 = Convert.ToInt32(dgvExcel[10, row.Index].Value);

                    //instruccion para mandar los datos a la clase que hace la insercion de datos
                    biss.DetalleLote(T150);
                }   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No ha seleecionado ningún archivo de Excel !!!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: No se entiende que necesitas. Porque no agregas el codigo y un ejemplo?

Comment: Tu explicación es muy confusa deberías agregar el código y la estructura de tu tabla para entenderte bien que quieres lograr.

Comment: ya, lo modifique

Comment: Por favor no agregues imágenes es muy tedioso tener que revisar con imágenes mejor agrega el código que utilizas para el datagrid y la estructura de tu tabla.

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo esta bien.. solo que necesita mucho trabajo y detalle ;)

Comment: pues lo que esta despues del primer if, lo puse asi porque solo necesito un regitro, por eso no le puse ningun foreach, pero lo que esta dentro del foreach es donde tengo el problema, no se si le un switch o algo para que haga la inserción como lo quiero

Comment: lo que quieras.. que haga la insercion como vos queres. Intentalo. Lo que estas pidiendo no es un error. es que hay que hacerlo...

Comment: puede que esto te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201249/convertir-base-de-datos-access-a-extensi%C3%B3n-jql/201256?noredirect=1#comment376892_201256